# django model forms cant change field value in clean()

Tags: django, django-forms, alter, modelform

I have a simple model form, to which I've added a simple checkbox:

```
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
   more_info = models.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput())

   def clean(self):
        if 'more_info' not in self.cleaned_data:
             self.instance.details = ""
   class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('details', 'address',  ) # more fields
```

But this does not work and the 'details' fields is still updated by the user value even if the checkbox is not selected (and the `if` block is executed, debugged).  I've also tried changing `self.cleaned_data['details']` instead of `self.instance.details` but it does not work either.

This is not so important, by in the client side I have a simple javascript code which hide/show the details field if the checkbox is selected.

Answer (score 1):

```
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    more_info = models.BooleanField(required=False)
    
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        if not cleaned_data['more_info']:
            cleaned_data['details'] = ''
        return cleaned_data
```

From [Customizing validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/):

> This method [`clean()`] can return a completely different dictionary if it wishes, which will be used as the `cleaned_data`.

Also:

1. `CheckboxInput` is default widget for `BooleanField`.
2. [`BooleanField` note](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.BooleanField):

   > If you want to include a boolean in your form that can be either `True` or `False` (e.g. a checked or unchecked checkbox), you must remember to pass in `required=False` when creating the `BooleanField`.

Comment: super() throws an error:
```
super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of updating `cleaned_data`, try overriding the `save` method instead

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, commit=True, *args, **kwargs):
    order = super(OrderForm, self).save(commit=False)
    if not self.cleaned_data.get('more_info', False):
         order.details = ""
    if commit:
        order.save()
    return order
```

Additionally, if you want to use the `clean` method you need to call super's clean first.

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(BailiffAddForm, self).clean()
    if not cleaned_data.get('more_info', False):
        ...
    return cleaned_data
```